# Migrate APT repository from flat to regular format transparently to the end user

Tags: debian, apt

I have some users, that are subscribed to my APT repository. It had been in "flat format", and its deb string looked like `deb http://uri directory/`.

Now, I am updating the repository format to standard `pool`/`dists` structure, so the deb string looks like `deb http://uri distribution main`.

Is there a way to migrate to the new-style repository format transparently for existing users?

Comment: Btw, the server is fully controlled by me, so I can make server-side url-manipulations, run scripts and so on.